# How to capture image with webcam?

Tags: c#

I want to capture image with webcam.

I use `WebCam_Capture.dll`. i add a `WebCamCapture` control in form.

when form load:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WebCamCapture.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = 1;
    WebCamCapture.Start(0);
}
```

and in ImageCaptured event :

```
private void WebCamCapture_ImageCaptured(object source, 
                                         WebCam_Capture.WebcamEventArgs e)
{
    this.pictureBox1.Image = e.WebCamImage;
}
```

but when i run, i get error:

> An error ocurred while capturing the video image. The video capture will now be terminated.
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use OpenCV Library.
it is an open source library for image proccessing from intel, developed by intel.
but, it has a wrapper for .net, you can download this wrapper from : [this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emgucv/?source=recommended)

Comment: Thanks, but when i use this code it is capturing image for one time but don't capture another time :(

Comment: the openCV is very simple to use, and u can see it's sample for webcam capture